# Why does Clark say "I didn't think it was even possible" when Lois tells him she's pregnant?

Tags: superman-and-lois

In Episode 1, Season 3 of Superman and Lois, when Lois tells Clark that she's pregnant why does Clark say "I didn't think it was even possible"? What is this referring to?

I mean, they already have two children, unless they were not Lois's children.

Why would Clark say this?

Comment: Well Clark *does* come from another planet- he could be thinking there were biological factors that would keep him from conceiving with a human woman.

Comment: @kingofpanes he already has two children with Lois - maybe you missed that part ...

Comment: https://youtu.be/OfHMaOQzAKk?feature=shared

Answer (score 0):

While not explicitly stated, it could mean that Clark believed his wife was no longer able to bear children.

At this point in the series, their boys are at least 16 years of age.  If after 16 years of being together they didn't have any more children, he perhaps assumed she was going through menopause.

I'm honestly surprised this didn't end up with kryptonite-laced divorce papers!